# Apache POI weird number formatting

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm trying to convert xls and xlsx files to csv using apache poi and I ran into some kind of problem which I don't know how to solve it. Basically, when a cell contains a big number, the code outputs that number into a weird format.

```
for (int cn = 0; cn < lastColumn; cn++) {
    Cell c = r.getCell(cn);
    if (c == null) {
        sb.append("|");
    } else {
        sb.append(c + "|");
    }
}
```

Example:

The spreadsheet contains this number in one cell: `84172870494`

And the output is this one: `8.4172870494E10`

Desired output: `84172870494`

Basically it adds a "." and "E%" at the end.

Comment: FYI that's called Scientific notation. It means take what's on the left of the `E` and multiply it by 10^(number on the right of the E) (in your case, `10^10`)

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca ok. And how can I change the format from scientific to the output that I want? I forgot to mention that this only happens when dealing with big numbers.

Comment: Do using [DataFormatter](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html). For example ... `DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter(); ` ... `sb.append(formatter.formatCellValue(c) + "|");`

Comment: @AxelRichter yeah, but what happens when dealing with text like cells?

Comment: if you have a string then you can use `int val = new BigDecimal(stringValue).intValue();`

Comment: @UlugToprak `84172870494` doesn't fit into an `int`, would need to use a `long`

Comment: Nothing happens. `DataFormatter` is able dealing with all kinds of cell types. For formula cells it also can be used together with `FormulaEvaluator`. Just read API and https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#CellContents.

Comment: @JonK you are correct, it will throw `ArithmeticException` if it doesn't fit into integer range

Answer (score 1):

You have to define your format in order to tell POI how to parse the data.

```
DataFormat format = wb.createDataFormat();
CellStyle style = wb.createCellStyle();
style.setDataFormat(format.getFormat("#.###############"));
cell.setCellStyle(style);
```

And check xls format :

https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#DataFormats
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/264372/how-to-control-and-understand-settings-in-the-format-cells-dialog-box

Comment: @user3776900 is the answer correct. If so could you accept it?